# AngularJS - set a model defined in a directives template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive defined like so:

```
angular.module('directives.myInput', [])
  .directive('myInput', function($parse, $http, $sce){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" />',
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.keyPressed = function(event){
          $scope.showDropdown = true;
          .
          .
          .
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

And then I have a button in html and directive above declared like so:

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
  <button ng-click="startNewLog()">Start</button>
  <div ng-controller="ItemNewCtrl">
     <myInput />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change/initialize ng-model="searchStr" model on a button ng-click. How can I do that?

Thanks guys,
Jani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, first of all you need call child controller with `$broadcast`. Since we don't use isolate scope, we just call directive method from child controller:

### [Short answer]

**No isolate scope example**

Demo 1 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1038/)**</kbd>

For isolate scope, I would map value to directive  that listens on value change automatically:

**Isolate scope example**

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1045/)**</kbd>

### [Full answer]

**No isolate scope example**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "IndexCtrl"> 
  <button ng-click="startNewLog()">Start</button>
   
  <div ng-controller="ItemNewCtrl">
      <my-input></my-input>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.startNewLog = function(){
     $scope.$broadcast('someEvent');
    };
    
});


app.controller('ItemNewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function() {
        $scope.callDirective();
    });
    
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.directive('myInput', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
       
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" />',
      controller: function($scope){
          
        $scope.searchStr;  
          
        $scope.keyPressed = function(event){
          $scope.showDropdown = true;
         
        }
      },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.callDirective = function() {
                scope.searchStr = 'callDirective';
            };
        }
    };
  });
```

**Isolate scope example**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "IndexCtrl"> 
  <button ng-click="startNewLog()">Start</button>
   
  <div ng-controller="ItemNewCtrl">
      <my-input my-model='contInput'></my-input>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.startNewLog = function(){
     $scope.$broadcast('someEvent');
    };
    
});


app.controller('ItemNewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.contInput = '';
    $scope.count = 0;
    
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function() {
        $scope.contInput = 'hey mate';
    });
    
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.directive('myInput', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
        scope:{searchStr: '=myModel'},
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" />',
      controller: function($scope){
          
        $scope.searchStr;  
          
        $scope.keyPressed = function(event){
          $scope.showDropdown = true;
         
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Hey thanks! But what if we have isolated scope inside directive?

Comment: Thanks, it works the first time when you click on button, but then if you change value in textbox and click on button again the initial value is not set. I just need a way to set the initial value when user clicks on a button. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: fixed, changed model name

Comment: Maxim, I owe you a beer :) Thank you for this, I marked solution as an answer. I just disovered, that it works for me also without $watch:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1046/

Comment: right, after I changed the model and mapped it to isolate scope, we don't need watch